# How can I split audio file into two using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, signal-processing

The `ffmpeg` [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-segment_002c-asegment) mentions that you can use the `|` to specify the timesteps to split the file. This command returns an error? Am I misusing it?

Command:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f segment=timestamps="60|150" -c copy output%03d.wav
>>> Requested output format 'segment=timestamps=60|150' is not a suitable output format
./tmp/test_split%03d.wav: Invalid argument
```

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f segment timestamps="60|150" -c copy output%03d.wav
>>> Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

What is the correct way to use the `|`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment), `segment` demuxer **does not** use `|` separator for what you want to do. I believe you are looking for this option:

> `segment_times times`
> Specify a list of split points. times contains **a list of comma separated duration specifications**, in increasing order. See also the segment_time option.

So, your command should read

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f segment -segment_times 60,150 output%03d.wav
```

Note that `-c copy` is not recommended if you want accurate split.

Comment: For audio only segmenting, copy is fine.